# Auto-create a pretty permalink for a bunch of posts

Tags: permalinks, slug, post-duplication

I have spammed many duplicate posts from one initial and now after editing them the url structure for them is something like `http://example.com/base-name-copy-20` where `base-name` is the slug of the duplicated initial post. Now, I could change the permalink for every one of them manually I know, but is there a way to create a slug for those duplicated posts anew ? I have edited them so they all have their own title now, but the permalink is already set. If I could reassign the permalinks the same way that wordpress automatically gives a slug for them initially would be nice.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding some interesting sources I ended up with this solution (added an extra function to take care of a few Dutch characters as well):

```
drop function if exists fn_remove_accents;
delimiter |
create function fn_remove_accents( textvalue varchar(20000) )
returns varchar(20000)
begin

set @textvalue = textvalue;

-- ACCENTS
set @withaccents = 'ŠšŽžÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿþƒ';
set @withoutaccents = 'SsZzAAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYYBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyybf';
set @count = length(@withaccents);

while @count > 0 do
    set @textvalue = replace(@textvalue, substring(@withaccents, @count, 1), substring(@withoutaccents, @count, 1));
    set @count = @count - 1;
end while;

-- SPECIAL CHARS
set @special = '!@#$%¨&*()_+=§¹²³£¢¬"`´{[^~}]<,>.:;?/°ºª+*|\\''';
set @count = length(@special);
while @count > 0 do
    set @textvalue = replace(@textvalue, substring(@special, @count, 1), '');
    set @count = @count - 1;
end while;

return @textvalue;

end
|

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `slugify`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` # I have no idea what this does
FUNCTION `slugify`(dirty_string varchar(200))
RETURNS varchar(200) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE x, y , z Int;
    Declare temp_string, allowed_chars, new_string VarChar(200);
    Declare is_allowed Bool;
    Declare c, check_char VarChar(1);

    set allowed_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-";
    set temp_string = fn_remove_accents(LOWER(dirty_string));
    Select temp_string Regexp('&') Into x;
    If x = 1 Then
        Set temp_string = replace(temp_string, '&', ' and ');
    End If;

    Select temp_string Regexp('[^a-z0-9]+') into x;
    If x = 1 then
        set z = 1;
        While z <= Char_length(temp_string) Do
            Set c = Substring(temp_string, z, 1);
            Set is_allowed = False;
            Set y = 1;
            Inner_Check: While y <= Char_length(allowed_chars) Do
                If (strCmp(ascii(Substring(allowed_chars,y,1)), Ascii(c)) = 0) Then
                    Set is_allowed = True;
                    Leave Inner_Check;
                End If;
                Set y = y + 1;
            End While;
            If is_allowed = False Then
                Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, c, '-');
            End If;

            set z = z + 1;
        End While;
    End If;

    Select temp_string Regexp("^-|-$|'") into x;
    If x = 1 Then
        Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, "'", '');
        Set z = Char_length(temp_string);
        Set y = Char_length(temp_string);
        Dash_check: While z > 1 Do
            If Strcmp(SubString(temp_string, -1, 1), '-') = 0 Then
                Set temp_string = Substring(temp_string,1, y-1);
                Set y = y - 1;
            Else
                Leave Dash_check;
            End If;
            Set z = z - 1;
        End While;
    End If;

    Repeat
        Select temp_string Regexp("--") into x;
        If x = 1 Then
            Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, "--", "-");
        End If;
    Until x <> 1 End Repeat;

    Return temp_string;
END;;
DELIMITER ;

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_name = slugify(post_title) WHERE post_name LIKE '%copy%' AND post_type = 'MY_POST_TYPE';
```

Explaining the query:
The first two functions are directly taken from sources 1 and 2, with a small edit to handle uppercase characters too.

Finally the update query will match on those duplicated posts that have the word `copy` in their slug, but depending on your case, you probably want to make this rule more strict. I want to run this query on my custom post type, so I added an extra check for the post type on the query, not a big deal.

The matched posts will be assigned a newly generated slug based on their title (post_title), alternatively you can specify a different source for the slug generation.

Sources:

[[1] Replace non-latin characters selectively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21409283/4730332)

[[2] Regenerate a slug from a free-text name](https://nastyhabit.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/mysql-slug-maker-function-aka-the-slugifier/)

[[3] WebElaine's answer (on this page)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257243/109095)

Answer (score 1):

Editing the permalink manually would be the safest route. If you're comfortable using phpMyAdmin, you could create a MySQL query to update them all in one batch. Slightly more work than auto-assigning a slug, but it doesn't require a lot of coding to try to re-calculate the slugs.

```
update wp_posts SET post_name = 'new-slug' WHERE post_name = 'old-slug';
```

(You can copy and paste this onto multiple lines and update as many as you like in one operation.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I have searched further and perfected my script to solve my case :)

Comment: Cool, perhaps you can edit the answer above to help others and mark as solved :)

Comment: I already posted my full solution, but can't mark it yet due to the 24 hours limitation.